# sed, awk - выбрать строки, в которых каждая последующая цифра больше предыдущей

Tags: sed, awk

Файл с буквенно-цифровыми строками известной определенной длины, но позиции цифр различны:

```
Z2aO9p6u8
4s5yI7H89
e0Dt14g67
3fR46i7I8
R2c0X346d
4U45v7gD9
```

желаемый тут выход:

```
4s5yI7H89
e0Dt14g67
3fR46i7I8
```

требуется выбрать строки, в которых N число цифр (в примере берем 5), и только те, в которых каждая последующая цифра больше по значению, чем предыдущая.
Собрал такую рабочую конструкцию:

```
cat file | grep -e '\([[:digit:]].*\)\{5\}' | while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*//g' | sed 's/./&:/g;s/$/'"${line}"'/' | awk -F":" '{if ($1 > $2 && $2 > $3 && $3 > $4 && $4 > $5) print$NF}' >> outfile; done
```

хотел избавиться от цикла, но не получилось применить к опеределенному полю удаление букв:

```
cat file | grep -e '\([[:digit:]].*\)\{5\}' | awk '{print$0":"$0}' | **sed 's/^[^:]*[[:alpha:]]//g'** ...
```

как кстати из `e0Dt14g67:e0Dt14g67` с помощью sed и awk сделать `01467:e0Dt14g67` ?

Вышеуказанная полная конструкция рабочая, но **хотелось бы без цикла** и **менее громоздкое**, более быстродействующее, предпочтительно все же наверное awk уместнее тут, но и sed тоже пригодится. Спасибо.

Comment: _Собрал такую рабочую конструкцию:_ ... `$1 > $2 && $2 > $3 && $3 > $4 && $4 > $5` ---- 
я так понимаю здесь может быть произвольное число(N) цифр, а точнее от 1 до 10 чисел  {0..9}, при 0 чисел задача не имеет смысла а при 10 числах будет только один правильный порядок 0123456789, то есть при таком подходе придется для каждого из 10-ти случаев писать соразмерное условие (в данном случае вы написали для 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N=5;cat FILE |awk '/([[:digit:]].*){'$N'}/{system("printf "$0" |tr -d \"[[:alpha:]]\"");print " "$0}' |awk '{system("printf "$1" |fold -w1 |sort -u |tr -d \"\n\"");print " "$0}' |awk '$1==$2{print $3}'
```

немного громоздко но зато универсально

Comment: Работает, спасибо, отдельное спасибо за функцию system, не знал про нее.